# Can I use PropTypes to express that a prop is a Promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

PropTypes are helpful for debugging because they show a warning when an expectations is not met. Beyond that, they're also nice to express the intention of how a component is meant to be used.

If I have a component that accepts a prop with a value that can be a promise, is there some way I can express that using PropTypes? I'm picturing either something direct like `PropTypes.promise`, or some way to express the concept of a "thenable" using building-block PropTypes.

Here is a highly simplified example to show my intended use case:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    someDataPromise: PropTypes.object // <-- can I be more expressive here?
  }

  state = {
    isLoading: false
  }

  async handleSubmit() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    const data = await this.props.someDataPromise;
    const response = await fetch(`/some/api/endpoint?data=${data}`);
    // do something with the response

    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  }

  render() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use an object with a particular shape e.g.

```
  PropTypes.shape({
     then: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
     catch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  })
```

Comment: Do you mean `PropTypes.shape` instead of `.objectOf`?

Comment: Yes. My mistake I think that is an old API - I will update my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Another way you can express that a prop is a Promise is to use `PropTypes.instanceOf()`.  Important caveat: this only works if your promises are instances of the Promise class:

```
static propTypes = {
  someDataPromise: PropTypes.instanceOf(Promise)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats the way you should think in react. React is nothing more then a advanced template engine, which means you have a "state" of data and the view representing this state. Using a promise as property means you have a not defined state, which is really hard to representing in the aspect of a view component. This is the main problem of programming, you can do everything you want, but when you use a framework you should follow the philosophy of the framework.

Long story short, don't use promises as property. Ensure a valid deterministic state before you pass properties to a view component. Maybe a global state like redux with thunk or redux observables will help you to handle async information.

Comment: Good point. Components should know what they are accepting, otherwise the PropTypes for a promise are a bit useless

Comment: Could there be a valid use case for passing a promise as a prop - e.g. creating a generic loading component for use across an application? In that case, the unresolved promise object with `then` and `catch` methods seems to be the needed state which the loading component relies on for rendering.

Comment: In general you have a global state like redux or mobx which representing the status of async operations like loading data ( isLoading: true ). In my opinion the best practice is to create a component at first for the worst case without data. With grey fields, and loading spinners which depends on global state data. If there are the necessary data it shows it, if not then not. After the global state receiving data the isLoading flag is set to false. For each async action you should use 3 actions, request, success and failture. This will help you to handle loading states.

Comment: Given that this post and answers were submitted a while ago, nowadays, promise components, aka lazy loading components, are very common. This helps developers dynamically inject components on-demand when needed to eliminate loading big component files even though they are not needed by user.